# Create a New Image File Extension in Windows 10 that operates like an image file

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, jpeg, png

I would like to add some new file extensions to my system.

Short Version - I would like to add PNG2, PNG3, PNG4, PNG5 exact copies of PNG and JPG2, JPG3, JPG4, JPG5 again, exact copies of JPG. I want them to open like a JPG or PNG, I want windows to know that they are essentially a JPG or a PNG.

Longer Version - I have a Movie Folder, Each Movie is in a separate folder, Each folder contains Movie Poster, DVD Cover, Wallpaper Artwork, Banner Art, Clear Background Art, Subtitles and of course the Movie. I will need to add a couple of new images in the near future, but for now, the 7 items, Each Item has the same Name, with a different file extension. MP4, SRT, JPG, JPE, JPEG, PNG and now PNG2. I create the File Extension, No worries, I can even tell Windows to Open a PNG2 with Paint Shop Pro. This system however doesn't work well with Windows, If I click on any image, it will open in Photo Viewer, Right click, open with Paint Shop Pro, look at a folder in Windows Explorer, Thumbnail with Pic, but not with PNG2. I thought I could just go into the registry and copy the PNG KEY and paste it as PNG2, but that doesn't work. Cant copy and paste keys in RegEdit, who knows why... Regardless, is this possible or am i dreaming. Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Try exporting the key you want to copy, modify and save it, then double click on the .reg file to merge it back in.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but as you put it, you're only dreaming :-)

File extension tells you how the [file is formatted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format). An example (partially) from real life: Wireshark understands `.pcap` and `.pcapng` (`.pcap` Next Generation) -files, but ACME Awesome Application* only understands the old `.pcap` format. I can hack Windows registry so that it thinks `.pcapng` is the same as `.pcap`. I can then double-click the `.pcapng` file and Windows will launch ACME. Which then will produce an error message in the vein of

> "Cannot open example.pcap, file format not correct".

`.pcapng` was developed from `.pcap`, but they aren't exact copies - "essentially same" doesn't cut it.

So you can't "add new extensions" to an operating system. If `.png2` -format is at some point developed (or has it already been?), you will need to install an update to PSP so it can open `.png2` files. Windows can't display a thumbnail or preview until Microsoft releases an update that adds OS-level support to `.png2`.

Hacking the registry is usually not a good idea, or even necessary. If you don't know exactly what you're doing, it's a fast way to hack your Windows into oblivion. Windows offers tools for tasks like changing the default application for a given file format. Or you might find it in the application's preferences. For example in Notepad++ preferences you can specify exactly what file extensions it will be opening by default, and NP++ will communicate your wishes to Windows which will make necessary OS-level adjustments.

**Can't be bothered to search for an actual Win app like Cocoa Packet Analyzer that only understands .pcap*